# find sequential gap with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Given nodes with a numeric property x.
Is it possible using cypher to find gaps in x?

```
{i1:Item {num:1}}
{i2:Item {num:2}}
{i3:Item {num:4}}
{i4:Item {num:5}}
{i5:Item {num:6}}
{i6:Item {num:10}}
```

In the above case we could return the start and end of gaps or anything else that would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have relationships connecting your Item nodes in the order you specified you could use a query like this to find any "gaps" of more than 1 between two Item nodes:

```
MATCH (i1:Item)-[:NEXT]->(i2:Item)
WHERE i2.num-i1.num > 1 
RETURN i1,i2
```

[Here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=bxpikp) is a Neo4j console demonstrating this.

**Edit**

Without using relationships between Item nodes you just need to first sort a collection of Item nodes before looking for gaps of more than 1:

```
MATCH (i:Item) WITH i ORDER BY i.num ASC WITH collect(i) AS items
UNWIND range(0,size(items)-2) AS idx
WITH items[idx] AS i1, items[idx+1] AS i2 WHERE i2.num - i1.num > 1
RETURN i1, i2
```

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to answer this, but unfortunately the nodes are not lined to each other.

Comment: @cechode see my edit, it is possible without using relationships as well. Just need to be sure to sort the Item nodes first.

Comment: though i just ended up just pulling the ids to the client to process i love that i learned something new for next time.

 awesomeness :)  thank you @william-lyon